# Приводит ли перекрестный вызов doGet() и doPost к deadlock?

Tags: java, многопоточность, servlet

Во многих ресурсах можно найти вопрос для интервью о том как вызвать deadlock в сервлете, и везде говориться о том что нужно вызвать в теле `doPost()` метод `doGet()` и наоборот в  теле `doGet()` метод `doPost()` [и вот один из них, вопрос №15.](http://www.journaldev.com/2015/servlet-interview-questions-and-answers)

Но возникает вопрос не фольклор ли это? Deadlock предполагает что потоки засыпают и ждут что у них будет вызван `notify()` или `notifyAll()`. Но при перекрестном вызове нет никаких `wait()` или `notify()`. Или есть?